# Unable to copy json block

Tags: json, powershell

I'm trying to copy condition block from id 106 to id 107 with script below; however, I got error "ConvertFrom-Json : Invalid JSON primitive:". Am I missing something? Please advise.

```
$a = Get-Content 'C:\DevOps\mytest.json' -raw | ConvertFrom-Json
$condition = $a | select -expand environments | select -expand conditions
Write-Host $condition[0]
$a | add-member -Name $condition[1].name -value (Convertfrom-Json  $condition[0]) -MemberType NoteProperty
Write-Host $update
$a | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 20 | set content 'C:\DevOps\updatedmytest.json'
```

The JSON file contains:

```
{
"source":  "userInterface",
"id":  25,
"revision":  3,
"environments":  [
                     {
                         "id":  106,
                         "conditions":  [
                                            {
                                                "name":  "ReleaseStarted",
                                                "conditionType":  "event",
                                                "value":  ""
                                            }
                                        ]
                     },
                     {
                         "id":  107,
                         "conditions":  [

                                        ]
                     }
                 ]
}
```

Best Regards,

Andy Pham

Comment: Here is my json file

Comment: This is PowerShell? You should tag it appropriately -- folks who know JSON but not PowerShell may not be much use here.

Comment: You can't index into a `PSCustomObject`, for one, and secondly, you need to read the documentation and understand basic PowerShell syntax..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message you are receiving is because you convert the JSON into a PowerShell Object and then saved it into the variable `$a`. `$condition` then is still a PowerShell object that you have expanded and is not JSON. So `-value (Convertfrom-Json  $condition[0])` doesn't work because it's already converted.

Convert to an object, make changes directly to the object, convert from the object.

```
$ConvertedJSON = Get-Content 'C:\DevOps\mytest.json' -Raw | ConvertFrom-Json
$ConvertedJSON.environments[1].conditions = $ConvertedJSON.environments[0].conditions
$ConvertedJSON | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 20 | Set-Content 'C:\DevOps\updatedmytest.json'
```

Alternatively, you could use `Where-Object` to filter for the ids.

```
$ConvertedJSON = Get-Content 'C:\DevOps\mytest.json' -Raw | ConvertFrom-Json
($ConvertedJSON.environments | Where-Object {$_.id -eq 107}).conditions = ($ConvertedJSON.environments | Where-Object {$_.id -eq 106}).conditions
$ConvertedJSON | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 20 | Set-Content 'C:\DevOps\updatedmytest.json'
```